# BillingFlowParams in Google In App Billing unable to start biling using real sku

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, in-app-subscription, play-billing-library

i have written these code which for sure fetching the skus from api, becoz its printing in log the fetched skus, but when i am setting the sku using **.setSku()** OR **.setType()** OR even directly **.setSkuDetails()** still the billingFlowParams isnt getting build, but these same code is working when i pass **android.test.purchased** to **.setSku()**. I couldnt get whee i am doing mistake. Any help will be appricated.

```
SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder()

    List<String> Skus=new ArrayList<>();
    Skus.add("sms_100103");
    Skus.add("sms_500105");
    params.setSkusList(Skus).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
    mBillingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), new SkuDetailsResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSkuDetailsResponse(int responseCode, List<SkuDetails> skuDetailsList) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: "+responseCode+" 1."+skuDetailsList.get(1));
            BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                    .setSku(skuDetailsList.get(1).getSku())
                    .setType(skuDetailsList.get(1).getType())
                    .build();
          int res=  mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow((Activity) context,flowParams);
            Log.d(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: "+res);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The code is correct, so would be good if you state the error code that you get.

Answer (score 2):

Codes have now changed:

```
public void attemptPurchase(String skuID){
SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
List<String> Skus=new ArrayList<>();
Skus.add(skuID);
params.setSkusList(Skus).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
billingClient.querySkuDetailsAsync(params.build(), (billingResult, list) -> {
    Log.d(TAG, "onSkuDetailsResponse: "+billingResult.getResponseCode()+" 1."+list.toString());
    BillingFlowParams flowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
            .setSkuDetails( list.get( 0 ) )
            .build();
    BillingResult responseCode = billingClient.launchBillingFlow(this, flowParams);
} );
}
```